# Converting datetime.datetime.second to an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

I'm trying to convert `datetime.datetime.second` to an integer in Python 3. I would like to round this value and then use the integer value in the function `datetime.time(hour=h,minute=m,second=s)` where `h`, `m` and `s` represent integers. I'm currently getting an error message which reads as such:

```
    s = int(datetime.datetime.second)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'getset_descriptor'
```

Below is a snippet of my code which shows what I'm trying to do.

```
s = int(datetime.datetime.second)
#code to be added here should round s to nearest 0 or 5
m = int(datetime.datetime.minute)
h = int(datetime.datetime.hour)
t0 = datetime.time(hour=h,minute=m,second=s)
```

Please could someone explain why this type conversion does not work, what is `datetime.datetime.second` actually returning and what solutions there are to my problem.

I expected the code to return the number of seconds in the current time. E.g if it is 10:29:34 when the code is run I expected `s` to be set to 34. I was trying to round the number of seconds to `0` or `5`. So in this case I expected to round the number of seconds to `35`, then get the value for `10` and `29` and store them in `h` and `m` respectively. Then put those values in `datetime.time()` and display that time later in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`datetime.datetime.second` does not give you the current time. It is not an object you generally want to use; it is an implementation detail of the `datetime.datetime` class.

To get the current time as a `datetime.time()` object, use the [`datetime.datetime.now()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now), then use the [`.time()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.time) on the returned `datetime` instance:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now().time()
```

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 6, 10, 29, 9, 758417)
>>> datetime.datetime.now().time()
datetime.time(10, 29, 11, 837654)
```

If you need to manipulate these values, you can use the [`time.replace()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.replace) to create a new `datetime.time()` instance with the updated value.

So to round your seconds value, you could use:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now().time()
now_rounded = now.replace(second=int(5 * round(now.second / 5)))  # round to nearest multiple of 5
```

To be precise, `datetime.datetime.second`, `datetime.datetime.minute` and `datetime.datetime.hour` are [descriptor objects](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), letting you access the internal information of a `datetime.datetime` instance; it is these objects that make the attributes `.second`, `.minute` and `.hour` on instances of the `datetime.datetime` class:

```
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> dt.second
26
>>> datetime.datetime.second.__get__(dt, datetime.datetime)
26
```

Comment: Thanks so much for clarifying this issue.